# Telerik Tab Control - Only the currently SelectedPage shows controls visibility correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using the 2013 Q3 Telerik Tab control in a C# WinForms project.  If I test the .Visible property of a control placed on a Page in the Tab then it will always return false unless I Select the page.  Is there another property besides .Visible that can be used to test the Visibility of a control on a Page without having to select it?

Comment: Why would you expect control's `Visible` property to be `true` if it's not visible? Tell us more about what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: That is an interesting philosophical point that we have discussed in the office.  The control isn't actually visible because the tab isn't visible.  But if the page WAS visible then the control on the page would be visible.  So - are there two different properties or how do you derive the controls that are visible on a non visible page without selecting it?

Comment: We're having issues with Validation on Tab controls because we only want to validate against Visible controls.  But when we test against controls on Pages on Tabs if the tab is not selected the control visibility returns false and doesn't validate correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my dilatation:
You should not change the native meaning of the control's properties. Period. I asked in a comment what were you trying to achieve, because I suspected that you're basing some UI logic on some control's visibility, which in my opinion isn't too good approach. The visibility should be bound to the background logic, not the oposite. You're hiding controls for some reason, because at some point something happened - so keep track of that "something" instead of inspecting its results. IMO the `Visibility` property should be set, but never checked.

Alternatively if it's not possible to change the concept for some reason, as a workaround I'd attach a handler to the `VisibleChanged` event and set `Enabled` property if the sender is not a tab control - then by checking against `Enabled` property you'd know whether the control is in use or not. I find it difficult to imagine a situation in which I'd need to check whether a control is visible.

Comment: In an ideal world I agree with what you're saying.  We're converting some ridiculously complex Access forms over to C# and phase 1 is just a straight code conversion.  Access doesn't have this Visibility issue.  To my mind there should be a way of querying the actual visibility property of a control regardless of whether it is a child to a parent control or not.  Apparently this isn't the case.  Thanks for you feedback.